# How to rename HSQLDB catalog in JUNIT

Tags: hibernate, schema, junit4, hsqldb, catalog

When using embedded HSQLDB to unit test, it seems the schema and/or the catalog defined in the hibernate entity mapping file can't be handled correctly. The hibernate mapping looks like

```
<class name="ca.zl.Orders" table="Orders" schema="dbo" catalog="db1">
```

With the property "hibernate.connection.url" set to "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1", I always got the following errors

> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport: user lacks privilege or object not found: DB1
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport: invalid schema name: DBO

This seems caused by HSQLDB by default only has one catalog named "PUBLIC", see [document here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html).

I can't change the hibernate entity mapping, I don't want to use other database engine (I know H2DB can handle this). Can anyone shed a light on how to make HSQLDB work in this unit test context?

Comment: `create schema db1`?

Comment: If you have to use a catalog name, rename the default one. `ALTER CATALOG PUBLIC RENAME TO DB1`